# integral representation of $\zeta(2)$

Tags: calculus

How does one show that

$\zeta(2)=\int_{0 \leq t_1 \leq t_2 \leq 1} \frac{dt_1}{1-t_1} \wedge \frac{dt_2}{t_2}$

Here $\zeta(2)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}$.

I tried to do the following:

1) separate the integral into 
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{dt_1}{1-t_1} \int_{t_1}^1 \frac{dt_2}{t_2}
$$

2) then $\int_{t_1}^1 \frac{dt_2}{t_2}=-log(t_1)$

3) on the other hand, $\frac{1}{1-t_1}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} t_1^n$

so I guess one has to develop also $-\log(t_1)$ into a power series, multiply both and then integrate term by term to get $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$. Unfortuntely I couldn't do this last step, would anyone be so kind to help me?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming a complex logarithm:

$\zeta(2)=2-\int_0^1 \ln(t)\ln(1-t) dt$.

Answer (score 3):

One doesn't need to develop $-\log t_1$ into  power series. Note that

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1 t^n\log t\,dt &= \left[\frac{1}{n+1}t^{n+1}\log t\right]_0^1 - \frac{1}{n+1} \int_0^1 t^{n+1} \cdot\frac{d\log t}{dt}\,dt\\
&= -\frac{1}{n+1}\int_0^1 t^n\,dt\\
&= - \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}.
\end{align}$$

Now interchange summation and integration in

$$\int_0^1 (-\log t_1)\sum_{n=0}^\infty t_1^n\,dt_1,$$

which by the monotone convergence theorem is allowed.

Answer (score 1):

$$I=-\int^1_0 \frac{\log(t)}{1-t}dt=-\int^1_0 \frac{\log(1-t)}{t}dt=\sum \frac{1}{k^2}$$